# Migrating projects from 2005 VS to 2010 VS using compatibility mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2008

I have large number of projects (~1500 C++ projects) that are compiled using VS2005. Since VS2005 is going out of support in few months i have to find a quick workaround to migrate to a supported version. I got some suggestions on certain compatibility compilation flag with Visual Studio.

Please answer following queries:

1. Is there such a flag which i can set for VS2005 and use it to in my Visual Studio 2010 version so that i need not change any code or project setup files?
2. If there is such flag how to enable it?
3. Is 2010 the latest version or not?
4. If there is no such flag what is the effort required for migration to VS2008 version?

Comment: VS2008, VS2010, VS2012, VS2013, VS2015. You can see how far you have been left behind.

Comment: Agreed..but the cost involved was so much(unsupported third party code blocks,pressing customer issues/enhancements etc) that this task never came up for us.Now it is absolutely necessary for us...so finding a workaround and then once i have bought enough time from our customers we can deal with this in coming years correctly by upgrading everythig to 2015 version

Comment: Microsoft does have related materials for each major release upgrade, and now you will have to run it in a fast forwarding way, and take care of third party code too. Hiring an expert might help too. Microsoft also sells consulting services.

Comment: Sure...but just wanted to know whether such a flag exists or not .If it does i can buy some time to do things right

Comment: based on the changes I am aware of, there is no magic flag to let your code run without modifications.

Comment: Thanks....is it possible to somehow tweak the newer compiler like v10.0 and v9.0 to generate binaries of v8.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

VS2008 and VS2010 can still target the .Net 2.0 Framework so no compiler changes should be necessary.

We did find one important difference between setup projects going from VS2005 to either 2008 or 2010. In 2005, setup projects for a Windows Service only asks for credentials on the initial install. Running updates with newer installs didn't prompt again.  With 2008 and 2010, it asks for credentials every time by default.

To stop the repeated prompts, right-click the installer project and choose View > Custom Actions. Set the Install Condition to

```
NOT PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED
```

and the Commit CustomActionData to

```
/OldProductCode="[PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED]"
```